# How to make 600 schema at a time(to have 600 room)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I am doing a hostel project so i need to allocated 600 rooms at an instant in case of additional room update,i may need to delete 300 rooms in case of room deletion but i dont know how
my room schema is

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const roomSchema=new Schema({
    Room_number:{
                   type:String,
                   required:true
                   },
    Roommates:{
                   type:Array
                   },
    Allocated: {
                    type:Boolean,
                    default:false
                     },
    Occupied:  {
                     type:Boolean,
                     default:false
                    },
    Batch:{
                     type:String
                    }                                                

},{
    versionKey: false // You should be aware of the outcome after set to false
})


var Room = mongoose.model('room', roomSchema);

module.exports = Room;
```

i wanna have to build 600 rooms with room numbers and all else as it is

Comment: You mean you like to create 600 databases? Certainly a bad design.

Comment: i wanna create 600 rooms,so i thought i will assign each room as a schema,if this design is bad can u please suggest a better one

Comment: Yes, put all into a single collection, i.e. 600 documents.